# How to make a angular service listen to an event without injecting it?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service

I have a login module , on login I will Fire event

$rootScope.$broadcast('onlogin');

I have another service timerService, which will listen to the onLogin event , after that it will start a timer to validate the session.

Since timerService has not been injected , it is not created and will not listen to event .

how to overcome this problem? I don't want to inject the timerService.

Comment: Why you don't want to inject service you are going to use?

Comment: I dont want to inject it cause jshint task will throw error saying you have injected the timerService but not used. TimerService is only responsible for listening to login/logout events in order to start and stop the timer.

Comment: Why not inject the timer service and instead of broadcast call a method from service, jshint will not complain (if that's so important) and it'll be easier to debug, I don't know the size of your app but if you focus on broadcasts your code will quickly become unmaintainable, I find 2way data binding much more convenient across bigger teams

Comment: I dint get your point and how two way binding will solve this problem? It is all about how to make timerService aware of login & logout or some other scenarios. Can you give some code examples? where i can see some practical implementation